# Change CSS with JS / jQuery when hash value in URL changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, addeventlistener

I have 6 `100vw` and `100vh` divs on a page and a right aligned fixed nav bar.

Each of these divs has an id# from 1 - 6

The **nav bar** has 6 list items links which point to the `id` of the `div`,

for example:

```
<ul>
    <li id="list-item-1"><a href="#1"></a></li>
    <li id="list-item-2"><a href="#2"></a></li>
    <li id="list-item-3"><a href="#3"></a></li>
    <li id="list-item-4"><a href="#4"></a></li>
    <li id="list-item-5"><a href="#5"></a></li>
    <li id="list-item-6"><a href="#6"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I am using scroll spy to nicely 'scroll' to the targeted div.

This nicely places the `id` value in the ur.

for example:

mywebsite.com/#1
or
mywebsite.com/#2
etc

What I would like to do however is **IF** the url contains `#1` or `#2` or whatever number it may be, the list item background changes color.

I originally tried an active/not active class, however, this is done on the scroll and click so a listener for a click won't always work.

I have seen quite a few examples from previous questions on here, however the the closest I could get would be something like this:

```
function locationChange() {
 if(location.hash == "#1") {
   $('#list-item-1').css('background-color', '#333333');
   $('#list-item-2').css('background-color', '#333333');
 } else {
   $('#list-item-1').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
   $('#list-item-2').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
 }
);
window.addEventListener("hashchange", locationChange(), false);
```

With the above code, the page sometimes loads with list item 1 changed, which is good, it picks up the `#1` on page load, however when I click or scroll through the page, the others are not picked up.

(I have only supplied a small amount above, my actual code applies this to all list items.)

Any help / suggestions / example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a working example, I believe the issue is within this line:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", locationChange(), false);
```

Adding a listener is a right course of action, but you are calling your function when you are defining the listener.  Changing `locationChange()` to `locationChange` will not immediately invoke the function and instead pass a handle to the function:

```
function locationChange() {
 if(location.hash == "#1") {
   $('#list-item-1').css('background-color', '#333333');
   $('#list-item-2').css('background-color', '#333333');
 } else {
   $('#list-item-1').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
   $('#list-item-2').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
 }
);
window.addEventListener("hashchange", locationChange, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I shall make the adjustment and get back to you.